# Is it possible to remove recipes in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to remove a original recipe from your minecraft world in anyway? Or make it unavailable to craft? I have tried to find a answer but I only found how to remove custom made recipes. My goal is to be able to change the recipe of a item in anyway I want. You can add a custom made recipe but the problem is that the original recipe will still be there. Here is a example, I want a diamond sword to be crafted with 3 diamonds, 2 sticks and maybe a emerald. That would be so much harder to make than the original recipe right? But here comes the problem, they can still make the diamond sword with 1 stick and 2 diamonds and that will make my recipe usless.

Comment: Yes, should be possible using the [`/recipe` command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/recipe). If not, a data pack that overwrites the recipe with something impossible. I'll write a proper answer soon, but that should already point you into the right direction.

Comment: I should have mentioned it in my question, but I have tried the recipe command but did not find any solution. But I need to say that I'm not that good with the recipe command and have only used it once before.

Comment: The wiki is your friend. And the new autocomplete.

Comment: Have you set `/gamerule doLimitedCrafting` to true?  If you remove the vanilla diamond sword recipe from the players when the get it, then their only option will be to use the new recipe that you're providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! Thanks to Mbraedley and Fabian. So what I did was that I used the command /gamerule doLimitedCrafting then after that I just removed every recipe and then gave them my recipe. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted using the checkmark to indicate that it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just usually forget bcs you need to wait 24 hours.